# How to get the Application name/fullpath in a servlet deployed in WebLogic

Tags: jakarta-ee, servlets, weblogic

Just like we can get the domain root directory from **weblogic.management.DomainDir**

```
String root = DomainDir.getRootDir() ;
```

and domain name from **weblogic.management.configuration.DomainMBean**

```
DomainMBean domainMBean = MBeanUtils.getDomainMBean();
String domainName = domainMBean.getName() ;
```

How can i get , the application name in which the servlet is deployed from inside the same servlet ? Which API from weblogic provides that information ?

for eg : 
**application path** = Middleware/user_projects/domains/Domain_1/servers/AdminServer/upload/webapp1. war

and **application name** = webapp1. war

Edited by: Tom on Mar 31, 2011 7:27 PM

Comment: Please include a link to your topic on the other forum from where you copypasted the question. This way we can also track any updates.

Comment: http://forums.oracle.com/forums/message.jspa?messageID=9484658#9484658  - same question in OTN forums. no answers yet.

Comment: Can you elaborate in non-Weblogic terms what exactly the "application name/fullpath" represents? Eventually with an example? The basic Servlet API also offers some methods to reveal server specific information.

Comment: @BalusC edited the post. added more details.

Comment: This information is unfortunately not directly available by Servlet API, no. You can at highest get the root folder where the WAR is been expanded, which would in your case be `Middleware/user_projects/domains/Domain_1/servers/AdminServer/upload/webapp1` (only and only if Weblogic expands the WAR in same root folder and uses the WAR filename as expanded folder name). Let me know if this is acceptable, then I'll post an answer how to do it.

Comment: @BalusC Yes i agree its probably not available through Servlet API . BUt how about through the weblogic APIs ? -  like weblogic.management.DomainDir - is a method along with WLS , not part of the std java packages. Any similar ones available which would give me what i require , may be using AppDeploymentMBean or DeploymentMBean ?

Comment: @BalusC .. ohk how can i get the expansion location using servlet APIs ..? i can extract the app name from that path also . Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I dont have a working example to hand, but try

`getComponentName()` and `getModuleURI()` from the

weblogic.management.runtime.[WebAppComponentRuntimeMBean](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e13945/weblogic/management/runtime/WebAppComponentRuntimeMBean.html)